# Scientific name of a certain plant from Philippines

Tags: botany, species-identification

[image]

Can someone tell me what is the possible scientific name of this plant? The seller told me it was sun rise plant but I can't seem to find it in the internet.

**Location:** Santa Rosa Laguna, Philippines

Comment: Please add a location to help us know where in the world you got it

Comment: Santa Rosa Laguna, Philippines